# Booting system without full network configuration without internet

Tags: 12.04, boot

I have an ubuntu 12.04 LTS, that is not connected to internet.

When I'm booting my system I have "Booting system without full network configuration" and it takes  about 15 min to boot.

Are there any way to reduce booting time?

Comment: What does `ifconfig` tell you?

Comment: I have loop connection(127.0.0.1 and IP, from modem, using COM port).
But I don't have ethernet connection.